# kadmin cannot list principals "requires list privileges"

Tags: linux, centos, security, kerberos, freeipa

I can authenticate fine via kadmin however cannot list principals?

```
[root@server ~]# kadmin -p admin
Authenticating as principal admin with password.
Password for admin@org.domain.com: 
kadmin:  listprincs 
get_principals: Operation requires ``list'' privilege while retrieving list.
kadmin:
```

any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to operate on principals in FreeIPA, use 'ipa' command.

1. All users have Kerberos keys by default, so

   `ipa user-find`

   would give you all users (use `ipa user-find --help` to see limiting criteria)
2. All hosts are Kerberos principals by default, so

   `ipa host-find`

   would give you all host/fqdn@REALM principals.
3. All services are Kerberos principals and they are owned by hosts, so

   `ipa service-find`

   would give you list of all services and if their entries have `Keytab: true` it means they are Kerberos principals with defined keytab.

Use `ipa service-mod` if you need to change parameters of the service. Use `ipa-getkeytab` to retrieve a keytab for any of the principals.

Operations through kadmin/kadmin.local are not supported in FreeIPA.

Comment: Very concise, thanks. Is this in the IPA docs?

Comment: Sort of, not so concise. You can file a documentation bug if you like to see it in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your `kdc.conf` has an `acl_file` entry pointing to a different location, you should create/edit `/var/lib/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl`, `kadm5.acl(5)`. However, this is for plain MIT-krb5. FreeIPA probably has its own methods for this.